# What C# language features help you to reduce lines of code and improve readability?

Tags: c#, resharper, language-features, code-readability

I came across a C# language feature today courtesy of ReSharper, the ?? operator. This helped make the code even more concise than my initial attempt. See below for iteration in improving lines/length/readability of code.

A first attempt could be something like..

```
if (usersEmail == null)
  userName = firstName;
else
  userName = usersEmail;
```

Refactored to..

```
userName = usersEmail == null ? firstName : usersEmail;
```

Initially I thought the above would be the most efficient/concise version, but there is a third step...

```
userName = usersEmail ?? firstName;
```

Id like to know if you have any similar examples where C# language features help with reducing lines of code and improving readability?

Comment: wiki ?? Also this has numerous answers...

Comment: Should probably be community wiki.

Comment: I don't agree that the tenerary operator improves readbility

Comment: @benPearce for people that know what it does it wouldn't differ a lot

Comment: Creating regions can help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This thread has a lot of gems: [Hidden Features of C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033/hidden-features-of-c)  (including the one you mentioned)

Answer (score 4):

the using block, LINQ, anonymous delegates, the list would just go on..

C# has a very nice habit of introducing features in every major release that cut down the amount of code that you have to write.

Answer (score 3):

The `var` keyword for implicit static typing and automatic properties are two good examples.

Answer (score 1):

Using using keyword

Answer (score 1):

Extension methods.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ queries allowing you to express the query criteria better than a foreach loop